# How do i aggregate the order amount for the products into one row

Tags: sql

Using the adventureworks database i am wanting to return the total amount ordered for each product. Came up with 2-queries however confused how to aggregate the total amount into one row for each product. The first query returns multiple orders of each product id with amounts. Added a 'rollup' clause but now NULL values are returned. is the rollup the correct function to use here and how do i get the total amount of each product ordered into one result row? am i over complicating this....thanks!

first query:

```
select p.productid, p.name, sum(od.unitprice - od.unitpricediscount) *  
       od.orderqty as total_amount
from Production.product p
join sales.SalesOrderDetail od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
group by p.productid, p.name, od.UnitPrice, od.UnitPriceDiscount,   
od.OrderQty
order by p.productid;
```

Sample of Return:

```
707 Sport-100 Helmet, Red   93.573
707 Sport-100 Helmet, Red   77.9775
707 Sport-100 Helmet, Red   150.4989
707 Sport-100 Helmet, Red   200.6652
707 Sport-100 Helmet, Red   313.7231
707 Sport-100 Helmet, Red   3754.689
707 Sport-100 Helmet, Red   1986.8716
707 Sport-100 Helmet, Red   1469.58
```

Second Query:

```
select p.productid, p.name, sum(od.unitprice - od.unitpricediscount) * 
od.orderqty as total_amount
from Production.product p
join sales.SalesOrderDetail od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
group by p.productid, rollup(p.name), od.UnitPrice, od.UnitPriceDiscount,  
od.OrderQty
order by p.productid;
```

Example return set:

```
707 NULL    187.146
707 NULL    124.764
707 NULL    249.528
707 NULL    167.221
707 NULL    200.6652
707 NULL    313.7231
707 NULL    383.89
707 NULL    1635.1065
```

Comment: tried that but receive error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'sales.SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: intended result is to aggregate productid totals into one row. ProdID 707 = total_amount and so on for all products.

Comment: Got it figured out. forgot to wrap my select list = dumb beginner mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your group by contains the price and discount, so no summary takes place. Try this:

```
select p.productid, p.name, sum(od.unitprice - 
od.unitpricediscount) *  
       od.orderqty as total_amount
from Production.product p
join sales.SalesOrderDetail od on p.ProductID = 
od.ProductID
group by p.productid, p.name
order by p.productid;
```

Comment: that was it plus the fact i wasn't wrapping the sum function as an aggregate.